# Batch File to write to event viewer

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have a batch file that runs a richcopy program, I am wanting to monitor the errorlevel so far i have got this

IF (%ERRORLEVEL% == 0) goto OK
else IF (%ERRORLEVEL% == 3010) goto Report

:Report

:OK 
END

What I am wanting to do is to report the error to the event viewer so that it can be monitored via another application that monitors the event logs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `EVENTCREATE` to write to the event log.

An example would be:

```
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /L APPLICATION /ID 100 /D "This is your error message."
```

More information can be found at the [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490899.aspx).

**EDIT**

In your case, try this.  Your parenthesis and use of == may be throwing things off.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 3010 goto OK    

EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /L APPLICATION /ID 100 /D "This is your error message." 

:OK 

EXIT
```

This way, if the error level isn't 3010, it always skips to the OK method, in case you get something other than 0 or 3010.

Comment: Thats great but it reports every time to the event viewer even on success?

Comment: Revised my answer based on the event always firing

Comment: It is helpful to include the /so option, to indicate a source (other than System).  Otherwise the formatting of the message will fail.